# How to get a new tag accepted?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Recently, I [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454022/a-prolog-for-prolog) to add the tag [iso-prolog](/questions/tagged/iso-prolog). However, [Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168868/charles), who describes himself as "a proud member of the New Tag Deletionist Cabal" removed this tag. We have tags [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog) as such, as well as for each implementation, like [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog), [gnu-prolog](/questions/tagged/gnu-prolog). Questions related to the ISO standard of Prolog thus have no tag currently.  For this reason, I tried to add it. Is there a way to do so?

Edit: Problem solved!

Comment: That looks like a perfectly reasonable tag to me, unlike a lot of new tags.

Comment: the question on the other hand isn't great - try adding it through existing questions which it's appropriate for.

Comment: The question in question is in fact one of the top items for ISO/IEC JTC1/SC22/WG17.

Comment: "So what are your favorite predicates?" is not a great fit for SO it's chatty and doesn't have a right or wrong answer

Comment: Do you think that adding the tag to another question will solve the problem? What, if it is then again deleted?

Answer (score 3):

I did a brief search of Prolog-related questions and tags before nuking it, and somehow I *completely* missed that there are already other prefixed Prolog tags.

In retrospect, it was indeed probably questionable and I won't get in the way of recreating it.  However, please do try to find other questions related to that specific Prolog variant.  The more questions you can add a new tag to, the better the likelyhood that it'll gain traction and be usable by the community.

Lately I've found myself adding new tags to old questions almost as much as nuking tags that don't need to exist.  It's something I wish people would do more of when creating new tags.  Creating a new tag *just* for your own question is silly.

Comment: Thank you. I have added a wiki entry and retagged some questions!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a reasonable tag to have in general, I think it was probably removed because it showed in the new tags list on only 1 question, which was already closed.

If you think it has value then adding it to all the existing questions shows that quite clearly to anyone looking at the newly created tags. Subscribing and adding a tag wiki helps too.

Comment: I did start to tag one question to see what happens before putting more work into it. And what happens with a tag wiki, if the tag is deleted? Is there some "safe sandbox" to avoid that all the work is lost?

Comment: @false - there is a list of orphaned tag wikis available to moderators. If you created the wiki then raise the issue here for a moderator to go looking.

Comment: @ChrisF Thank you. I have started to add the wiki entry.

Answer (score 1):

Well, upon comparing activity in relevant tags, removal you refer to looks quite questionable to me.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1ILU.jpg]